# Using Django bulk_create gives UNIQUE constraint failed:solgeo_hourly.id

Tags: django

I have two models, namely Project and Hourly. Whenever a new project is created, I want to also generate 8760 new Hourly instances.

There are two methods, one is very costly since 8760 times a new row is written to the database, i.e.:

```
for i in range(0, 24):
    clock_time=i*3600
    hourly = Hourly.objects.create(project=project, clock_time=clock_time)
    hourly.save()
```

The other method is by using the Django bulk_create(hourlys) method, which works fine whenever I use the default Hourly() constructor. However I want to use my custom Hourly.objects.create() function. This however gives an UNIQUE constraint error for hourly.id, i.e.:

```
class HourlyManager(models.Manager):
    """"""
    def create(self, project, clock_time):
        hourly = super().create(project=project, clock_time=clock_time)
        hourly.local_civil_time = services.calc_local_civil_time(clock_time, 
                                                                 project.TMZ, 
                                                                 project.lon)
        hourly.save()
        return hourly


class ProjectManager(models.Manager):
    """"""
    def create(self, owner, project_name, TMZ, lat, lon):
        project = super().create(owner=owner, project_name=project_name, TMZ=TMZ, lat=lat, lon=lon)
        project.save()

        hourlys = []
        for i in range(0, 24):
            hourlys.append(Hourly.objects.create(project=project, clock_time=clock_time))
        Hourly.objects.bulk_create(hourlys)

        return project


class Project(models.Model):
    objects = ProjectManager()

    owner           = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    TMZ             = models.FloatField(default=0)
    lat             = models.FloatField(default=0)  # Radians
    lon             = models.FloatField(default=0)  # Radians


class Hourly(models.Model):
    objects = HourlyManager()

    project             = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='hourlys', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clock_time          = models.FloatField(default=0) 
    local_civil_time    = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@arne, this is the wrong way to bulk_create.

```
    hourlys = []
    for i in range(0, 24):
        hourlys.append(Hourly.objects.create(project=project, 
     clock_time=clock_time))
     Hourly.objects.bulk_create(hourlys)
```

The proper way is you pass the attributes to the Hourly object creating a list of that. A compressed version would look like this here below.

```
hourlys = [Hourly(project=project, clock_time=i*3600) for i in range(24)]
hourlys_objects = Hourly.objects.bulk_create(hourlys)
```

See [link here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/optimization/) for more

As explained above when you call Hourly.objects.create the object is created (with a hit to the database also defeating the purpose of using bulk_create optimization).

Answer (score 3):

When you are calling `hourlys.append(Hourly.objects.create(project=project, clock_time=clock_time))`, object of `Hourly` model is already created in the database, and you are appending that object in the `hourlys` list. Each object in that list already has an `id` associated with it. So when you are trying to do `bulk_create` in the next line, django tries to create new object with the same id and thus fails the unique constraint.

Comment: But is there a way to still use bulk_create, while using the Hourly.object.create() method?

Comment: As far as I know, you can not.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with and it seems to work fine. I use bulk_create in the ProjectManager, than I create a new classmethod (@classmethod) called create() for the Hourly model. This solves the problem that the hourlys do not posess a unique ID. I'm not exactly why but it does seem to work fine.

```
class ProjectManager(models.Manager):
    """"""
    def create(self, owner, project_name, TMZ, lat, lon):
        project = super().create(owner=owner, project_name=project_name, TMZ=TMZ, lat=lat, lon=lon) # "CREATED BY PROJECTMANAGER"
        project.save()

        hourlys = []
        for i in range(0, 24):
            clock_time = i*3600
            hourlys.append(Hourly.create(project=project, clock_time=clock_time))
        Hourly.objects.bulk_create(hourlys)
        return project


class Project(models.Model):
    objects = ProjectManager()

    owner           = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    TMZ             = models.FloatField(default=0)
    lat             = models.FloatField(default=0)  # Radians
    lon             = models.FloatField(default=0)  # Radians


class Hourly(models.Model):
    #objects = HourlyManager()

    project             = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='hourlys', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clock_time          = models.FloatField(default=0) # One year = 31557600 seconds primary_key=True, 
    declination         = models.FloatField(default=0)
    local_civil_time    = models.FloatField(default=0)
    equation_of_time    = models.FloatField(default=0)
    solar_time          = models.FloatField(default=0)
    solar_hour_angle    = models.FloatField(default=0)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, project, clock_time):
        hourly = cls(project=project, clock_time=clock_time)
        hourly.declination      = services.calc_declination(clock_time)
        hourly.local_civil_time = services.calc_local_civil_time(clock_time, 
                                                                 project.TMZ, 
                                                                 project.lon)
        hourly.equation_of_time = services.calc_equation_of_time(clock_time)
        hourly.solar_time       = services.calc_solar_time(hourly.local_civil_time,
                                                           hourly.equation_of_time)
        hourly.solar_hour_angle = services.calc_solar_hour_angle(hourly.solar_time)
        return hourly
```